# Dialogflow Caching

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

My problem is that I am trying to cache some values on dialogflow and perform a different action if the values exists.

Is there any way to check the existence of say session entity or entity or context or anything else and then perform different actions based on whether they exist or not. In one case the action needs to be a webhook fulfillment, in the other case it needs to be a text reply without any webhook

Comment: You have tagged this with both `dialogflow-es` and `dialogflow-cx`. Which platform are you using, since the approach would be different in each. It would also help if you can show either the configuration that you've tried that isn't working or provide screen shots illustrating what you've tried and what, exactly, you're having problems with.

Comment: I am using dialogflow-es
Consider this, I have an intent which has a webhook fulfillment. The fulfillment sets a context and a sessionEntityIntent. 
When this intent gets matched again, I want to return this context value or the sesionEntityIntent value. How can I do this?

Comment: Can you please further explain your use case with an example and edit your question properly? I don't fully get what you are trying to do so I can't detail if the set up you are trying to accomplish can be done in a different way.